# If $f’(x) = \sin x + (\sin4x)(\cos x)$, then $f’(2x^2 + \pi/2) $is?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

If $$f'(x) = \sin x + \sin4x \cdot \cos x,$$ then $$f'(2x^2 + \pi/2)$$ is?

Given answer: $$4x\cos(2x^2) – 4x\sin(8x^2) \sin(2x^2)$$

I tried and I'm getting the answer as $\cos(2x^2) - \sin(8x^2)\sin(2x^2)$

Comment: I think $$f'(x) = \sin x + \sin4x \cdot \cos x$$  should be $$f(x) = \sin x + \sin4x \cdot \cos x,$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee No, the question is as such.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee does changing so yield any result?

Comment: @NandakishorNair There are a number of notational errors in your question.  Are you sure you have transcribed it accurately?

Comment: @NandakishorNair, That will make the question & answer matched

Comment: @ErickWong I'm not sure if it's a typo in the problem set, but it's typed as such itself. I'm sure.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Assuming it's so, I still can't arrive at the given answer. How do you do it?

Comment: @NandakishorNair, Have you noticed my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the closest approximation to the question that actually makes sense:

Suppose $$f'(x) = \sin x + \sin 4x \cdot \cos x.$$

Let $g(x) = f(2x^2 + \frac\pi2)$.  Then
$$g'(x) = 4x \big(\!\cos(2x^2) - \sin(8x^2)\sin(2x^2) \big).$$

That would make two typos in the question: the lack of parentheses around the expression multiplied by $4x$, and the mistaken use of $f'(2x^2+\frac\pi2)$ to refer to $g'(x)$ (I think you correctly computed the former but the answer suggests the latter).

Comment: why do you say f′(2x^2+π/2) is not equal to g'(x)? I don't understand.

Comment: Can you please write the complete solution? I'm confused. Please?

Comment: @NandakishorNair The difference is simple order of operations.  $g'(x)$ is the derivative of the function you get from substituting $2x^2 + \pi/2$ into $f(x)$.  $f'(2x^2 + \pi/2)$ is simply the substitution of $2x^2+\pi/2$ into the derivative $f'(x)$, which is what you computed.  That's partly why I asked if you transcribed the question exactly, since the distinction is subtle and you have might written one while meaning the other.

Answer (score 1):

If $$f(x) = \sin x+\sin 4x\cdot \cos x\;,$$ Then put $$\displaystyle x = 2x^2+\frac{\pi}{2}$$

So $$\displaystyle f\left(2x^2+\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \sin \left(2x^2+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\sin \left(8x^2+4\pi\right)\cdot \cos \left(2x^2+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

So $$\displaystyle f\left(2x^2+\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \cos 2x^2-\sin 4x^2\cdot \sin 2x^2$$

Above we have used $$\displaystyle \bullet\; \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\phi\right) = \cos \phi$$ and $$\displaystyle \bullet\; \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\phi\right) = -\sin \phi$$

and $$\displaystyle \bullet\; \sin (2\pi+\phi) = \sin \phi$$

Comment: there is a typo in the forth line from the end. It's -sin(8x^2).sin(2x^2)

Comment: I too got the same answer. So, that means the provided answer is wrong, right?

Comment: @NandakishorNair I do believe the answer is wrong.  There is no reasonable interpretation I can see where the chain rule factor of $4x$ appears only on the first term of the sum and not the second.

Comment: @Eric you are right. factor 4x is there on both terms. I'm sorry.

Comment: I think that the OP wants the derivative with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f\'(x) = \sin x + \sin 4x \cos x$$

We need to find $f\'(2x^2+\pi/2)$.

Now

$$f\'(2x^2+π/2) = f\'(2x^2+π/2).Derivative of (2x^2+π/2)$$

$$ = {\sin (2x^2+π/2) + \sin 4(2x^2+π/2).Cos(2x^2+π/2)}.4x$$

$$ = 4x{\cos(2x^2) - \sin(8x^2).\sin(2x^2)}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I did a partial edit, please do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

$$f\left(2x^2+\dfrac\pi2\right)=\sin\left(2x^2+\dfrac\pi2\right)+\sin4\left(2x^2+\dfrac\pi2\right)\cos\left(2x^2+\dfrac\pi2\right)$$

Now $\sin\left(\dfrac\pi2+y\right)=+\cos y$ and $\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2+y\right)=-\sin y$

Now use chain rule like $$\dfrac{d\{\cos(2x^2)\}}{dx}=\dfrac{d\{\cos(2x^2)\}}{d(2x^2)}\cdot\dfrac{d(2x^2)}{dx}=-\sin(2x^2)\cdot4x$$

Comment: Note that the derivative of $f(2x^2+\pi/2)$ isn't the same as $f'(2x^2+\pi/2)$.  The question seems to have a lot of flaws.

Answer (score -1):

@N Nair ...I was solving arihant today and came across the same problem (the reason I am here :p lol) and I think I have got a relevant answer to the question but have some doubts too.
 f'(2x^2+π/2) does not mean df(2x^2+π/2)/dx....(i)
It rather means ... df(2x^2+π/2)/d(2x^2+π/2) .....(ii)
so, case (i) which gives answer 4x{cos(2x^2)-sin(8x^2)sin(2x^2)} is WRONG and so I think the answer provided is WRONG.
and case (ii) will yield the answer cos(2x^2)-sin(8x^2)sin(2x^2) which according to me is CORRECT and thus YOUR ANSWER is CORRECT.
Any arguement to this? Please let me know :)